# Transpose a group of repeating columns in large horizontal dataframe into a new vertical dataframe using Scala or PySpark in databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, transpose

This question although may seem previously answered it is not.  All transposing seem to relate to one column and pivoting the data in that column.  I want to make a vertical table from a horizontal set of columns, for example:-

Take this example:-

| MyPrimaryKey | Insurer_Factor_1_Name | Insurer_Factor_1_Code | Insurer_Factor_1_Value | Insurer_Factor_2_Name | Insurer_Factor_2_Code | Insurer_Factor_2_Value | Insurer_Factor_[n]_Name | Insurer_Factor_[n]_Code | Insurer_Factor_[n]_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XX-ABCDEF-1234-ABCDEF123 | Special | SP1 | 2500 | Awesome | AW2 | 3500 | ecetera | etc | 999999 |

**[n]** being any number of iterations

transforming it into a new vertical representation dataframe:-

| MyPrimaryKey | Insurer_Factor_ID | Insurer_Factor_Name | Insurer_Factor_Code | Insurer_Factor_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XX-ABCDEF-1234-ABCDEF123 | 1 | Special | SP1 | 2500 |
| XX-ABCDEF-1234-ABCDEF123 | 2 | Awesome | AW2 | 3500 |
| XX-ABCDEF-1234-ABCDEF123 | [n] | ecetera | etc | 999999 |

There is also the possibility that the “Code” column may be missing and we only receive the name and value therefore requiring null to be added to the code column.

I've searched High and low for this, but there just doesn't seem to be anything out there?

Also there could be many rows in the first example...

Comment: As shown in your resulting table, your primary key is no longer a primary key (not unique). So you can just drop that column, and loop through the row 3 at a time and then add it to another data frame?

Comment: It's ok the "MyPrimaryKey" and "Insurer_FactorID" will become a new compound key, but spark doesn't care about that thankfully

Comment: Any luck funding an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you haven't found it is that there is not a magic trick to move a 'interstingly' designed table into a well designed table.  You are going to have to hand code a query to either union the rows into your table, or select arrays that you then explode.

Sure you could probably write some code to generate the SQL that you want, but really they're isn't a good feature to magically translate this `feature` format into a row based format.

Comment: The "interestingly" design is due to a flattened schema for sending 1 file rather than multiple files.  Unfortunately I have 6000 columns to go through that probably will fit into 6 tables. Also the number of iterations can fluctuate so I need a way of doing the transform dynamically.  If the iterations were fixed you could code for it easily

Answer (score 0):

In order of preference:

Revisit your decision to send multiple files:
It sounds like it would save a lot of work if you just sent multiple files.

Change the column schema:
Put a delimiter (every 4th column) into the column schema allowing us to see the rows.  We can then suck the file in as rows. Using a delimiter.

Write your own custom datasource:
You can use the [existing text one as a example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/text/TextFileFormat.scala) for how you can write your own, that cold interpret every 3 columns as a row.

Write a custom UDF that takes all columns as a parameter and returns an array of rows, that you then call explode on to turn them into rows.  This will be slow so I give it to you as the final option.

Comment: No choice on the multiple files front, not us sending the file we are the recipient.

Comment: Can't modify the source in any way and as the repeats may vary I need a dynamic way of doing this.

A UDF might be the way forward but I've no idea how to do that

Comment: It was worth a shot... I get it, we get what we get but maybe you could point out the cost involved with developing a solution to fix the issue and see if that changes peoples perspective.  (It may not change a thing but it's worth pointing out the issue.)

Comment: I"m not suggesting to modify the source code, I'm suggesting that you use it as a template for how to build your own custom datasource.

Comment: UDF don't have great performance but they are simple to write.  (Cant' vectorize with UDFs)

Comment: The file comes from a third party in parquet after it has already been converted from XML embedded in a json output.  The whole 6000 column record is flattened into one big mega table.  I want to deconstruct it to reduce query cost in the long run and make it easier to consume.  I think I'm just going to have to use a user defined function but please if I could get a pointer in the right direction how you would do that and how to use it in this context, I am very new to spark in general

Answer (score 0):

*** WARNING ***
This is going to use up a lot of memory. with 6000 rows it will be slow and may run out of memory.  If it works great but I suggest you code your own data source as that likely is a better/faster strategy.

If you want to do this with a UDF and you are only doing this with a couple of row you can do this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

/* spark.sql("select * from info").show();
+----+-------+----+
|type|db_type|info|
+----+-------+----+
| bot|  x_bot|   x|
| bot|  x_bnt|   x|
| per|   xper|   b|
+----+-------+----+ */
 val schema = ArrayType(new StructType().add("name","string").add("info","string"))
val myUDF = udf((s: Row) => {
    Seq( Row( s.get(0).toString, s.get(1).toString ), Row(s.get(2).toString, s.get(2).toString ) )
},schema)
val records = spark.sql("select * from info");
val arrayRecords = records.select( myUDF(struct(records.columns.map(records(_)) : _*)).alias("Arrays") )
arrayRecords.select( explode(arrayRecords("Arrays")).alias("myCol") )
.select( col("myCol.*").show()

+----+-----+
|name| info|
+----+-----+
| bot|x_bot|
|   x|    x|
| bot|x_bnt|
|   x|    x|
| per| xper|
|   b|    b|
+----+-----+
```

- Sudo code
- Create schema for rows.
- create udf (with schema) (here I only show small manipulation but you can obviously use more complicated logic in your case)
- select data,
- Apply udf,
- Explode Array.